# jquery animation moving and stopping

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I got a div with an image inside it using query

```
                $('#super').animate({
                left:'150px'
                }, {
                duration: 10000,});
```

What iam trying to figure out is how to stop and start animation. So for example it will start to move left 150px and then will stop for 2 seconds and then move left 300px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('#super').animate({left : '-=150'}).delay(2000).animate({left : '-=300'});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/E7akr/

(You can add duration, easing and complete settings to the `.animate()` calls as desired - obviously the key thing here is the [`.delay()` method](http://api.jquery.com/delay).)

Comment: Just a quick question will this work for an image then inside a div?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what's in the div, if you move the div its contents will go with it. Try it out and see...